# Proving the identity $(\tan^2(x)+1)(\cos^2(-x)-1)=-\tan^2(x)$

Tags: trigonometry

Proving the trigonometric identity $(\tan{^2x}+1)(\cos{^2(-x)}-1)=-\tan{^2x}$ has been quite the challenge. I have so far attempted using simply the basic trigonometric identities based on the Pythagorean Theorem. I am unsure if these basic identities are unsuitable for the situation or if I am not looking at the right angle to tackle this problem.

Comment: $tan^{2}(x)+1=sec^{2}(x)=\frac 1 {cos^{2}(x)}$ and $1-cos^{2}(-x)=1-cos^{2}(x)=sin^{2}(x)$.

Comment: I wonder how you failed to solve this using the Pythagorean theorem, this is straightforward.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

Multiply the two members by $\cos^2x$ (certainly nonzero):

$$(\sin^2x+\cos^2x)(\cos^2x-1)=-\sin^2x.$$

Comment: I do not believe your work is correct.

Comment: @James I strongly believe his work is correct and elegant.

Comment: sin^2(x)+cos^2(x)=1; cos^2(x)-1=-sin^2(x); if the two side were to both be divided by -sin^2(x), the result would be 1=1, which does prove the identity but not with the result ending including -tan^2(x).

Comment: I understand the approach you are taking though. Thank you!

Comment: @James: my approach is fully correct. Sorry to say, you don't understand the principle of proving identities. You can rewrite keeping the denominators, but this is unnecessary. By the way, we can multiply by $\cos^2x$ as this factor is guaranteed to be nonzero.

Comment: @Yves Daoust, with all due respect, you simply cannot leave the denominators as they are not a given. This goes for all mathematical proofs and is one of the fundamental concepts as I hope you have learned this. You must include all aspects of an equation for it to be true. This is in fact essential to mathematics in general. As for your comment upon my ability to prove identities, I am well experienced in this field. I did not mean to offend you if you feel offended but simply tweaked your explanation. As with everyone, we can improve. In no way, shape, or form did I mean to insult you.

Comment: In organic chemistry, there is no need for carbon to be denoted as between bonds as it is used so commonly in organic chemistry. In the case of mathematics as a whole, each equation is unique. Simply, mathematics requires all aspects to be denoted as nothing can be a given for all scenarios. I hope you understand.

Comment: @James: It is perfectly acceptable to prove an identity by transforming it in a reversible way. With this case, in multiplying-through by a non-zero expression ($\cos^2x$), Yves reduced the identity to an utter triviality; to recapture the original identity, one could simply reverse the process and divide the triviality by the same non-zero expression ... even so, the *essence* of the identity is already established in the transformed version. (Note: We may assume $\cos^2 x$ is non-zero, since the appearance of $\tan x$ restricts the domain of consideration appropriately.)

Comment: @James: if $c\ne0$, $a=b\iff ca=cb$. This is what you are missing. You don't have the correct experience in proving identities (no offense but I urge you to review your understanding of equivalence of identities), and you disregarded my comment that explained how to reshape the proof to your taste.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Shouldn't it actually be "divide" both sides by $\cos^2x$?

Comment: @ParasKhosla: there is indeed a before/after ambiguity. I am after.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I get it. Cheers :))

Answer (score 2):

Expanding gives $\sin^2x-\tan^2x+\cos^2x-1$. The undesired terms cancel because $\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Recall:

$$\begin{align}
\tan^2(x) - \sec^2(x) &= -1 \\
\sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x) &= 1
\end{align}$$

Thus,

$$\begin{align}
\tan^2(x) + 1 &= \sec^2(x)\\
\cos^2(x) - 1 &= -\sin^2(x)
\end{align}$$

We also note that $\cos(x)$ is an even function, and thus $\cos(-x) = \cos(x)$. Thus, the formula becomes:

$$(\tan^2(x) + 1)(\cos^2(-x) - 1) = -\sec^2(x)\sin^2(x) = - \frac{\sin^2(x)}{\cos^2(x)} = -\tan^2(x)$$

Answer (score 1):

1. $1+\tan^2x=\sec^2x$
2. $\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$
3. $\cos x=\cos(-x)$ i.e. $\cos x$ is an even function.
4. $\sec x=1/\cos x$

$$\underbrace{\left(1+\tan^2x\right)}_{=\sec^2x}\underbrace{\left(\cos^2(-x)-1\right)}_{\cos x\text{ is even function}}=-\sec^2x\cdot\sin^2x=-\tan^2x $$

Answer (score 0):

We know

- $(\tan x)' = 1 + \tan^2 x = \frac{1}{\cos^2 x}$ and
- $\cos (-x) = \cos x$

Now, it follows immediately
\begin{eqnarray*} (\tan^2(x)+1)(\cos^2(-x)-1)
& = & (\tan x)'\left(\frac{1}{(\tan x)'}-1\right) \\
& = & 1 - (\tan x)' \\
& = & 1 - (1 + \tan ^2 x) \\
& = & - \tan ^2 x \\
\end{eqnarray*}